Accidentally bumped the head and it is now offset mid-print; how can I save the print?
I tried to fix a very minor stringing during print and I accidentally bumped the head. As a result, it's now offset and printing spaghetti. I want to save the print but I'm new to this and I'm not sure how to go about it. So far I've simply taken record of which layer I was on though I'm not sure how far into that layer I was. I've also removed the stringing and gently filed with a small file from a fingernail set.
I figured I'd seek some guidance while it's paused and I'm getting some dinner. My plan for coming back to it is to manually edit the G-code and try to add a bit at the start of the G-code file that will either align with the corner or the very center of the piece that I can then use to manually force the offset so that it will print in alignment again. This is obviously not ideal, but I figured there would be an option for mid-print calibration but I can't seem to find one. I'd rather not lose the print and I'd like to tackle this issue now before it occurs again on future prints.
How do I save the print? the piece is still pretty much as it should be, definitely reckon it's within error margins. If I could align the head accurately and resume print from where I've paused (or preferably from slightly before that when I bumped the thing) then the print could probably be completed successfully.
My printer is a Creality Ender 3 v3 KE and I'm using the Creality print software.
I attempted to edit the G-code by simply deleting all the previous layers and inserting a homing instruction but for some reason, the print didn't begin with an unknown exception raised. I've now removed the piece from the printer bed and I'm going to try and print the remaining portion and bond them after the fact. I'm not sure how to go about cutting the model to the correct size, I've installed Freecad so if somebody knows how to go about this I would appreciate some tips.

Most slicers allow you to move the object in the Z axis, so that it gets 'cropped' below the bed. I did a quick trial with Creality Slicer 4.8 and I was able to move the Z by -30mm so that it only prints the top of the object.

Yes, thank you I discovered that. I think I still need to learn how to use a cad program though. I spent ten minutes trying to figure out how to cut the model with csg in freecad but couldn't quite get there before I decided I'll come back to the cad stuff tomorrow. I mean just using the gcode or some calipers to measure the piece then dropping the model in the slicer software by that offset on the z plane is quick and easy. I do wish the print could have continued from where it was. I don't know why it refused to run the print. I told it not to calibrate and just print but still failed.

How would you go about bonding the pieces after? In my case due to the way its cut off i will have 3 pieces printed seperately once i've run this through the printer. Im thinking strong adhesive or would you melt them together?

I would probably go with glue.

I'll give it a go! I've tried using my hot air gun yesterday for fixing something but there was some warping. i used it with less air while it was still on the bed this morning and fixed an issue before it became a problem but that wouldn't work for bonding two pieces. I guess i'd need to burn something as I'm pressing them together but glue seems easiest.
